# How to develop and deploy several different bots in Azure?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots

I have developed a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework v3 and C#.Net. I have also deployed the bot in Azure with in a resource group having necessary resources like App Service Plan, App Service, Bot Service etc. Now there is a requirement to create a new bot for different workflow. I want to know what are my chances to use my existing Azure resources. Should I create a new Bot service & App Service in same App Service Plan?
If anyone have created and deployed various different bots in Azure please share the strategy.

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends on your scenarios.

But considering that your different bots must run in parallel:

- App Service Plan can be reused, if its pricing is high enough to size to the demands of both bots
- Storage account can also be reused as it uses bot Id in its keys (but it would be better to specify different tables for each bot in your dependency injection if using Table Storage)
- App Service (where you are exposing your `/api/messages` endpoint) must be specific if you don't manage a special configuration
- App Bot Service (which is linked to this endpoint) must be specific also, as Bot Channel Registration is specific to each bot